# Como utilizar um formulário no componente irmão?

Tags: angular, typescript

Tenho um componente chamado `detail-paciente` em que contém um formulário com várias propriedades, sendo uma delas acompanhantes que é um FormArray. Quero utilizar o mesmo formulário deste componente em um componente filho, como eu poderia "herdar" as infomações do `form` para então utilizar do FormArray no componente filho `acompanhantes` que eu criei?

componente `detail-paciente`

```
public validation(): void {

    this.form = this.fb.group({

      pacienteId: ['', Validators.required],
      nomePaciente: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(9), Validators.maxLength(50)]],
      dataNascimento: ['', Validators.required],
      dataRegistro: [''],
      rg: [''],
      sexo: ['', Validators.required],
      acompanhantes: this.fb.array([]),
    });
  }
```

Como teste eu criei o FormArray de acompanhantes dentro do component `detail-paciente` e funciona
corretamente.

```
  get acompanhantes(): FormArray {
    return this.form.get('acompanhantes') as FormArray;
  }

  AddAcompanhante(): void {
    this.acompanhantes.push(this.CreateAcompanhante({ acompanhanteId: 0 } as Acompanhante));
  }

  CreateAcompanhante(acompanhante: Acompanhante): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      acompanhanteId: [acompanhante.acompanhanteId, Validators.required],
      nomeAcompanhante: [acompanhante.nomeAcompanhante, Validators.required],
      dataNascimento: [acompanhante.dataNascimento, Validators.required],
      sexo: [acompanhante.sexo, Validators.required],
      pacienteId: [],
    });
  }


    <div [formGroup]="form" class="col">
            <div formArrayName="acompanhantes" *ngFor="let acompanhante of acompanhantes.controls; let i=index">
              <h3>Test</h3>
              <fieldset [formGroupName]="i" class="form-group">
...
```

Como eu utilizo o código acima em um componente irmão?

Comment: Você pode passar o formulário através de um @Input() para o componente filho

Comment: E no caso se eu for passar do componente filho para outro componente filho seria com @Input() tbm?

Comment: Sim, você pode fazer dessa maneira. Porém quando começa a passar um atributo por muitas camadas (pai -> filho -> neto), é melhor criar um [Service para compartilhar os dados entre componentes](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/5-ways-to-share-data-between-angular-components-d656a7eb7f96#cf87).

Comment: Bom, sou iniciante em angular, e ainda fiquei na dúvida em como utilizar o Input/Output usando componentes irmãos, estou utilizando <router-outlet>, como eu defino a propriedade do formulário principal(form) na rota irmã? ex: [formAcompanhante]=form

Answer (score -1):

**1. Utilizando @Input()**

Se você tem acesso direto ao componente filho, você pode passar o formulário através da propriedade @Input()

```
<!-- app-pai.component.html -->
<app-pai>
  <app-filho [formulario]="form"></app-filho>
</app-pai>
```

---

```
/* app-filho.component.ts */
export class FilhoComponent {
  @Input() formulario: FormGroup;
}
```

**2. Utilizando um Service**

Agora, se você não tiver acesso ao componente filho, que acredito que seja seu caso, você pode criar um service para compartilhar o formulário entre os componentes.

[Fiz um exemplo no stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zayobd?file=src/app/data-shared.service.ts) demonstrando as 2 formas. Qualquer dúvida pode me perguntar.